# ruby handsoap documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, handsoap

Does anybody know some nice documentation about the ruby "handsoap" gem to get me started?

Thanks

Comment: http://wiki.github.com/troelskn/handsoap/recommendations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [the guide in the wiki](http://wiki.github.com/troelskn/handsoap/recommendations)? You can also find much more on [Handsoap](http://github.com/troelskn/handsoap/tree/master) in [the API docs](http://rdoc.info/projects/troelskn/handsoap).